Can't install Pillow ver 6.0.0 at Python 3.7.9 on mac M1 (python installed by arch -x86_64)
First, my venv setting is under arch -x86_64(brew86, pyenv86, python 3.7.9_x86)
but i couldn't install Pillow version 6.0.0 with this virtualenv.
here is all console messages I've got..
Building wheels for collected packages: Pillow
  Building wheel for Pillow (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/yanako/pjt/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/nq/cjn7n4ls1n94nqsn4ysr51zm0000gn/T/pip-install-mcdyaax1/Pillow/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/nq/cjn7n4ls1n94nqsn4ysr51zm0000gn/T/pip-install-mcdyaax1/Pillow/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/nq/cjn7n4ls1n94nqsn4ysr51zm0000gn/T/pip-wheel-thf_rrb0
       cwd: /private/var/folders/nq/cjn7n4ls1n94nqsn4ysr51zm0000gn/T/pip-install-mcdyaax1/Pillow/
  Complete output (174 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-14.4-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.macosx-14.4-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.4-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  ...
  running egg_info
  writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no files found matching '*.c'
  warning: no files found matching '*.h'
  warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.codecov.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'azure-pipelines.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
  no previously-included directories found matching '.azure-pipelines'
  no previously-included directories found matching '.travis'
  writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  running build_ext
  
  
  The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
  
  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/private/var/folders/nq/cjn7n4ls1n94nqsn4ysr51zm0000gn/T/pip-install-mcdyaax1/Pillow/setup.py", line 792, in <module>
      zip_safe=not (debug_build() or PLATFORM_MINGW), )
    File "/Users/yanako/pjt/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/Users/yanako/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/Users/yanako/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/Users/yanako/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/Users/yanako/pjt/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 368, in run
      self.run_command("build")
    File "/Users/yanako/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/Users/yanako/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/Users/yanako/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/Users/yanako/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/Users/yanako/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/Users/yanako/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "/private/var/folders/nq/cjn7n4ls1n94nqsn4ysr51zm0000gn/T/pip-install-mcdyaax1/Pillow/setup.py", line 606, in build_extensions
      raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
  __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib
  
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/private/var/folders/nq/cjn7n4ls1n94nqsn4ysr51zm0000gn/T/pip-install-mcdyaax1/Pillow/setup.py", line 804, in <module>
      raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
  __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
  
  The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
  
  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
  
  
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for Pillow
  Running setup.py clean for Pillow
Failed to build Pillow
Installing collected packages: Pillow, popbill, pycrypto, pycryptodome, pyexcel-xls, pyexcel-xlsx, XlsxWriter, pyexcel-xlsxw, pyodbc, qrcode, shellescape, uWSGI
    Running setup.py install for Pillow ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/yanako/pjt/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/nq/cjn7n4ls1n94nqsn4ysr51zm0000gn/T/pip-install-mcdyaax1/Pillow/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/nq/cjn7n4ls1n94nqsn4ysr51zm0000gn/T/pip-install-mcdyaax1/Pillow/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/nq/cjn7n4ls1n94nqsn4ysr51zm0000gn/T/pip-record-u0ju_7os/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/yanako/pjt/venv/include/site/python3.7/Pillow
         cwd: /private/var/folders/nq/cjn7n4ls1n94nqsn4ysr51zm0000gn/T/pip-install-mcdyaax1/Pillow/
    Complete output (176 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-14.4-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-14.4-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.4-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    ...
    running egg_info
    writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.c'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h'
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'azure-pipelines.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching '.azure-pipelines'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.travis'
    writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    
    
    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
    
    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/private/var/folders/nq/cjn7n4ls1n94nqsn4ysr51zm0000gn/T/pip-install-mcdyaax1/Pillow/setup.py", line 792, in <module>
        zip_safe=not (debug_build() or PLATFORM_MINGW), )
      File "/Users/yanako/pjt/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/Users/yanako/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/Users/yanako/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/Users/yanako/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Users/yanako/pjt/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/Users/yanako/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/Users/yanako/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/Users/yanako/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Users/yanako/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/Users/yanako/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/Users/yanako/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Users/yanako/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/private/var/folders/nq/cjn7n4ls1n94nqsn4ysr51zm0000gn/T/pip-install-mcdyaax1/Pillow/setup.py", line 606, in build_extensions
        raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/nq/cjn7n4ls1n94nqsn4ysr51zm0000gn/T/pip-install-mcdyaax1/Pillow/setup.py", line 804, in <module>
        raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
    
    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
    
    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
    
    
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/yanako/pjt/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/nq/cjn7n4ls1n94nqsn4ysr51zm0000gn/T/pip-install-mcdyaax1/Pillow/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/nq/cjn7n4ls1n94nqsn4ysr51zm0000gn/T/pip-install-mcdyaax1/Pillow/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/nq/cjn7n4ls1n94nqsn4ysr51zm0000gn/T/pip-record-u0ju_7os/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/yanako/pjt/venv/include/site/python3.7/Pillow Check the logs for full command output.


I've tried to install all my requirements with "--no-binary :all:" flag..
with this, i installed pandas and some libraries.
and for this, I've tried to reinstall 'zlib' by brew
   brew install zlib
   brew install jpeg
   export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib"
   export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include"

